# Need help understanding conditional directives with MASM

Tags: assembly, x86, masm

I am trying to implement the following c code in MASM using MASM directives:

```
if ( a > b )
    a = a - 1;
else
    if ( b >= c )
        b = b − 2;
    else
        if ( c > d)
            c = c + d;
        else
            d = d / 2;
```

This is my attempt:

```
.if (a > b)
sub a, 1
.elseif b >= c1
sub b, 2
.elseif c1 > d
add c1, d
.else
mov eax, d
cdq
mov ebx, 2
idiv ebx
mov d, eax
.endif
.endif
```

I feel like my logic is sound yet no matter what I change around to keep it intact I am getting errors. I am sure I have misunderstood something, but don't unsure about what.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, since you have only one opening `.if`, you only need one `.endif`. Second, at least if `a`, `b`, `c1`, and `d` are normal memory operands, you have a problem that most instructions can't use two memory operands (directly). For your typical comparisons, at least one of the operands most be in a register.

As an aside, I'd also indent `.if` (and such) code just like you normally would code in a higher level language. At least normally, I'd also use `dec` instead of `sub x, 1`, and probably `shr` instead of `idiv` to divide by 2.

Taking all of the above into account, you end up with something like this:

```
.model flat, c
.data
    a dd ?
    b dd ?
    c1 dd ?
    d dd ?

.code
junk proc
     mov eax, a
     mov ebx, b
     mov ecx, c1
     mov edx, d

    .if eax > ebx
        dec a
    .elseif ebx >= ecx
        sub b, 2
    .elseif ecx > edx
        add ecx, edx
        mov c1, ecx
    .else
        shr edx, 1
        mov d, edx
    .endif
junk endp

    end
```

This assembles just fine, at least for me.