# Invalid instruction operands when using if directive with masm

Tags: assembly, x86, masm

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [error A2070:invalid instruction operands with MASM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8585294/error-a2070invalid-instruction-operands-with-masm)
>   [Need help understanding conditional directives with MASM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8583772/need-help-understanding-conditional-directives-with-masm)

I am trying to implement the following basic codeblock. I am trying to implement a basic if, elseif, elseif block to learn to use the conditional directives in MASM, but can't seem to make the logic work.

```
.if a > b
sub a, 1
.elseif b >= c1
sub b, 2
.elseif c1 > d
mov eax, d
add c1, eax
.else
mov eax, d
cdq
mov ebx, 2
idiv ebx
mov d, eax
.endif
```

On the .if and .elseif lines I get the above error A2070.

Why? What is the actualy problem with my code?

Comment: @Mystical That question has been deleted.

Comment: Why do you keep deleting your questions only to ask them again? If you want to fix an error you can just edit it.

Comment: Because a question which was downvoted for no reason would likely go ignored, while simply posting anew with clarification works better, imo.

Comment: Only if it is done repeatedly and frequently according to that site.

Comment: A question with many negative votes makes me curious. I guess that many SO users tend to visit questions with extreme voting numbers, may it be positive or negative, more often

Comment: There's literally a list of your questions over this same code block.  We're going to keep flagging the abusive behavior until the moderators take action.  We come here to help people, but these selfish tactics eliminates much of our desire to help.

Comment: @SonnyOrdell You can get banned automatically for doing this repeatedly. The automatic abuse detection only triggers if you keep behaving badly; reposting a near-identical question because the first post didn't get responses is abuse anyway, and it could get you banned manually by a moderator. Please don't do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely MASM expects the compared entities to be directly encodable in a single `CMP` instruction. `CMP` supports the following pairs of operands:

- reg/mem, reg
- reg, reg/mem
- reg/mem, imm

Where `reg` is a register, `mem` is a memory location, `imm` is a numeric constant, `reg/mem` is either `reg` or `mem`. Thus, you can't compare directly two memory locations or two constants, such an operand combination isn't supported by the `CMP` instruction.